# How do I list all users and their Account IDs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am an Admin and I would like to list all my users and the Account IDs and/or Aliases. How do I do this?

Comment: One option: [Getting credential reports for your AWS account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html).

Answer (score 3):

Users can use cli command mentioned below

```
aws iam list-users
```

You can refer to [list-users — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-users.html)
for the better understanding.